# Why doesn't Javascript sorttable work in Ruby application?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a HTML table in my `/views/` file and want to sort some of the columns.  I've downloaded "sorttable.js" into my `public/javascript` folder and added the following in my file in views:

```
<script src="public/javascripts/sorttable.js"></script>
<table class="sortable">
```

Nothing is coming up.  Any ideas why?

Comment: I've changed your title and your tag.  Javascript is not the same thing (at all) as Java.  They're barely related.

Comment: Did u check is the javascript file loaded? In rails please use this to include javascript files: <%= javascript_include_tag "sorttable" %>

Comment: U add this between the head tags of your page.

Answer (score 0):

Try pointing the javascript to the proper folder: (you dont need to specify *public/*)

```
<script src="/javascripts/sorttable.js"></script>
<table class="sortable">
```

Comment: i have but with no luck, i get ActionController::UnknownAction (No action responded to javascripts

Comment: Ops! Sorry, I missed the preceding /. Fixed now... (Although using the Rails helper as suggested above is the preferred solution of course.)